# Remove DataGrid Row Clicking Image

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Trying to create a Datagrid and have users be able to remove a row by clicking an image.  Example of the generated window:

[image: Example DataGrid Window]

However, I can't figure out how to connect clicking on the image with the generated cell next to it that is read in by a text file.  Whenever I call for the value of that cell I can see `List`, but not it contents.

DataGrid XAML Code:

```
        <!-- Main Shared Drive Data Grid -->

        <DataGrid HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                  Height="309" 
                  VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                  Width="550" 
                  Margin="24,50,0,0" 
                  Name="SDDataGrid"
                  Background="Black"
                  BorderBrush="#26534e"
                  BorderThickness="4"
                  Loaded="DataGrid_Loaded"
                  AutoGenerateColumns="True"
                  IsReadOnly="True"
                  RowHeaderWidth="0"
                  HeadersVisibility="Column"
                  ColumnWidth="*">
            <DataGrid.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black"/>
                    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="SemiBold"/>
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#459289"/>
                    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,0,2,2"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#26534e"/>
                    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="4"/>
                    <Setter Property="Width" Value="Auto"/>
                </Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black"/>
                    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="SemiBold"/>
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#459289"/>
                    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1,1,0,2"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#26534e"/>
                    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="4"/>
                    <Setter Property="Width" Value="Auto"/>
                </Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,0,2,0"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#26534e"/>
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black"/>
                    <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="Do_Row_DoubleClick"/>
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.Resources>
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="58">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="Delete" Width="57"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="57">
                                <Button x:Name="deleteBtn" Width="53" Click="deleteBtn_Click">
                                    <Button.Template>
                                        <ControlTemplate>
                                            <Image Source="Assets/trash.png"
                                                   Stretch="None"/>
                                        </ControlTemplate>
                                    </Button.Template>
                                </Button>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

C# Code:

```
    // Shared Drive List
    List<Drives> _list;

    // Build The Drive List Object
    public class Drives
    {
        public string Filepath { get; set; }

        public Drives(string line)
        {
            string[] parts = line.Split(',');
            this.Filepath = parts[0];
        }
        public string GetLine()
        {
            return this.Filepath.ToString();
        }
    }

    // Loads DataGrid Of Window With Drive List
    private void DataGrid_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var drives = new List<Drives>();

        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(@"..\..\Data\SDrives.txt"))
        {
            while (true)
            {
                string line = reader.ReadLine();
                if (line == null)
                {
                    break;
                }
                drives.Add(new Drives(line));
            }
        }
        this._list = drives;
        var grid = SDDataGrid;
        grid.ItemsSource = drives;
    }

    // Adds User Submitted Filepath To Drive List And Reloads Window
    private void Add_Btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var drives = new List<Drives>();

        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"..\..\Data\SDrives.txt", append: true))
        {
            writer.WriteLine(FilepathTextBox.Text);
        }

        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(@"..\..\Data\SDrives.txt"))
        {
            while (true)
            {
                string line = reader.ReadLine();
                if (line == null)
                {
                    break;
                }
                drives.Add(new Drives(line));
            }
        }
        this._list = drives;
        var grid = SDDataGrid;
        grid.ItemsSource = drives;
    }

    // Launches Filepath When User Double Clicks
    private void Do_Row_DoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        var cellInfo = SDDataGrid.CurrentCell;
        {
            var column = cellInfo.Column as DataGridBoundColumn;
            if (column != null)
            {
                var element = new FrameworkElement() { DataContext = cellInfo.Item };
                BindingOperations.SetBinding(element, TagProperty, column.Binding);
                var cellValue = element.Tag;
                if (Directory.Exists(@"" + cellValue))
                {
                    Process.Start(@"" + cellValue);
                }
                else
                {
                    System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(@"" + cellValue + " is not a valid filepath.");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void deleteBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var selected = SDDataGrid.SelectedItem;
        Console.WriteLine(selected.ToString());
    }
```

Text File:

```
C:\Users\Edward\Desktop\Projects
C:\Users\Edward\Desktop\School
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I suggest to learn something about [MVVM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2009/february/patterns-wpf-apps-with-the-model-view-viewmodel-design-pattern) it gives you the power of **WPF**. And one of them is Command implementing `ICommand` interface.*

Let's assume that you don't want to dig into MVVM and want to get the solution here and now. *I'll show it here and now and **it's not MVVM** but there's some approaches widely used in MVVM*

If you want `DataGrid` to update its source when you change the collection simply use `ObservableCollection` instead of `List` and fire `PropertyChanged` event if you reassign the data property and keep the `DataGrid` up to date automatically.

**Let's go:**

1) Implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface for `Window`.

```csharp
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
```

add the code to the `Window` class

```csharp
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = null)
    => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
```

2) Set `Window.DataContext` to itself to tell `Binding` where it should find the target properties.

```csharp
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = this;
}
```

3) Make the data collection a Property, change `List` to `ObservableCollection` and fire `PropertyChanged` event in `set` clause. `ObservableCollection` is almost the same as `List`, so don't be afraid of using it.

```csharp
private ObservableCollection<Drives> _drivesList; // backing field, never interact with it
                                                  // but use DrivesList instead
public ObservableCollection<Drives> DrivesList
{
    get => _drivesList; // same as get { return _drivesList; } but shorter
    set
    {
        _drivesList = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

4) And bind `DataGrid` to it in xaml.

```xaml
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding DrivesList}"
          ...>
```

5) Here we're done with dynamic `DataGrid` updates. And as result we have some code redundancy and let's make a cleanup.

```csharp
private void DataGrid_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DrivesList = new ObservableCollection<Drives>();
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(@"..\..\Data\SDrives.txt"))
    {
        while (!reader.EndOfStream)
        {
            string line = reader.ReadLine();
            DrivesList.Add(new Drives(line));
        }
    }
}

private void Add_Btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string path = FilepathTextBox.Text;
    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"..\..\Data\SDrives.txt", append: true))
    {
        writer.WriteLine(path);
    }
    DrivesList.Add(new Drives(path));
}
```

**The answer to the question:**

6) But you'll get a problem with deletion because when you'll click a **Delete** button it will delete `SelectedItem` but not the row where's button located. The only solution is pass to the deletion method the row where's the button located. And the most friendly solution is Command.

6.1) Here's ready helper class for easy commands use. Just put it into the project outside of `Window` class: Right-click on the project in Solution Explerer, Select **Add** => **Class** => **RelayCommand.cs**. And add the following code there. *Add it once and use as many times as you need.*

Namespaces

```csharp
using System;
using System.Windows.Input;
```

The class

```
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    private readonly Action<object> _execute;
    private readonly Func<object, bool> _canExecute;

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Func<object, bool> canExecute = null)
    {
        _execute = execute;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter) => _canExecute == null || _canExecute(parameter);
    public void Execute(object parameter) => _execute(parameter);
}
```

6.2) Implementation of command in `Window` class

```csharp
private ICommand _deleteCommand;

public ICommand DeleteCommand => _deleteCommand ?? (_deleteCommand = new RelayCommand(parameter =>
{
    if (parameter is Drives drives)
    {
        DrivesList.Remove(drives);
        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"..\..\Data\SDrives.txt", append: false))
        {
            foreach(Drives drives in DrivesList)
            {
                writer.WriteLine(drives.Filepath);
            }
        }
    }
}));
```

6.3) And usage in xaml

```xaml
<Button Width="53"
        Command="{Binding DataContext.DeleteCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}"
        CommandParameter="{Binding}">
    <Button.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <Image Source="Assets/trash.png"
                   Stretch="None"/>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Button.Template>
</Button>
```

**Bonus part**

7) Also you may replace `Click` events with commands.

For example you have `Add` button

```xaml
<TextBox x:Name="FilepathTextBox"/>

<Button Content="Add" Click="Add_Btn_Click"/>
```

Replace with

```xaml
<TextBox x:Name="FilepathTextBox"/>

<Button Content="Add"
        Command="{Binding AddCommand}"
        CommandParameter="{Binding Text,ElementName=FilepathTextBox}"/>
```

and implement it in `Window` class

```csharp
private ICommand _addCommand;

public ICommand AddCommand => _addCommand ?? (_addCommand = new RelayCommand(parameter =>
{
    if (parameter is string path)
    {
        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"..\..\Data\SDrives.txt", append: true))
        {
            writer.WriteLine(path);
        }
        DrivesList.Add(new Drives(path));
    }
}));
```

In general Commands are not looks simpler than event handlers in `Button` case but it have different features. Such as disable button with condition `CanExecute`. You may try return `false` in `CanExecute` and the button become disabled. And as shown in `DataGrid` you may also pass any object via `CommandParameter`.

And the main feature is: Command can be located anywhere where you may set the Window's `DataContext` but Event handler can be located only in `Window` class. (Commands and Properties in MVVM are located in separate ViewModel class).

```csharp
public ICommand AddCommand => _addCommand ?? (_addCommand = new RelayCommand(parameter =>
{
    string path = (string)parameter;
    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"..\..\Data\SDrives.txt", append: true))
    {
        writer.WriteLine(path);
    }
    DrivesList.Add(new Drives(path));
},
parameter => parameter is string path && path.Length > 0));
             // Here's CanExecute, any condition here may be used.
             // This condition will prevent adding empty lines
             // and will disable the Button if TextBox is empty, automatically
```

Comment: The solution worked great using ObservableCollection for loading and adding, however it only deletes the row from the DatGrid, not from the text file it's referencing, so when the Window reloads the row reappears.  Playing around with that now to try and resolve.  Thanks for the help!  I need to look into MVVM, as this is going to be a rather large application I'm working on.

Comment: @Sanavi you may just overwrite the whole file content on deletion. And please don't dorget to mark the answer as accepted in case it was helpful.

Comment: Sorry, accepted answer, first time posing question heh - just trying to figure out now how to overwrite the file.

Comment: @Sanavi I've added an improvement to the `DeleteCommand` in the answer.